# How to save data into database from dynamically created text boxes

Tags: vb.net

I have dynamically created text boxes on flowlayout panel. The text box can be any number. I am trying to save those value(integer) from text box into database. It takes me a day to achieve this, and i am a newbie by the way. Please guide me how to achieve this. Thank you so much. I try to save into List(Of...) collection but it only returns last value.Here is how i am trying to achieve this. I declare shared list of List type in another class called clsHelper.

```
Private Sub saveIntoList(flp As FlowLayoutPanel)
    clsHelper.list = New List(Of String)
    For Each tb in flp.Controls
        If TypeOf tb Is TextBox Then
            txtNo = DirectCast(tb,TextBox)
            If txtNo.Name = "txtNo" Then
                clsHelper.list.Add(txtNo.Text)
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

[FlowLayoutPanel with six text boxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6MY2P.png)

Comment: Rephrase your question so the part of what is the actual problem is more clear.

Comment: I am curious to know, once you get a list, of indeterminate length, of strings  that may or may not be numbers, how is this to be saved to a database?

Comment: You don't need `If TypeOf tb Is TextBox Then` because you can filter in the `For Each` statement: `For Each tb in flp.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)()`.

Comment: When the textboxes are created, you could save references to them in a List(Of TextBox). Then you just need to iterate over that list when you want to save the data.

Comment: thank you so much for guiding me. I follow it and it is resolved now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is probably this `If` statement. Only the content of the `TextBox` whose name is `"txtNo"` is added to your `list`. The content of other `TextBoxes` with different names are not added. Remove the `If` and the content all `TextBoxes` will be added to your `list`.

```
If txtNo.Name = "txtNo" Then
    clsHelper.list.Add(txtNo.Text)
End If
```

If `TextBoxes` are not all immediate children of the `FlowLayoutPanel`, you will need to modify your code as follows, to recursively iterate all the controls hierarchy below the `FlowLayoutPanel`.

```
Private Sub saveIntoList(flp As FlowLayoutPanel)
    clsHelper.list = New List(Of String)
    _saveIntoList(flp)
End Sub

Private Sub _saveIntoList(control As Control)
    If TypeOf control Is TextBox Then
        clsHelper.list.Add(DirectCast(control, TextBox).Text)
        Return
    End If
    For Each child As Control In control.Controls
        _saveIntoList(child)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I remove If statement and it works, but it doesn't loop all the text boxes inside flowlayoutpanel. It only stores the content of last two text box. It does not matter how many text box is there. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Doru Bogyi - Difficult to tell without seeing your controls. However, the `Controls` property contains only the immediate children of a control. So, if a TextBox is inside a child control of the FlowLayoutPanel, your code will miss it. For each child, you need to recursively iterate through its children, if any.

Comment: I have used your code but it still catches only the content of last two text boxes. And i have posted the image of my 'FlowLayoutPanel' with six text boxes on my question above. Please help me have a look. This is my work related project and I am stuck at this stage. Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: @Doru Bogyi - Please post your updated code. Also, somehow, show that your FlowLayoutPanel has 6 textboxes (code behind the form).

Comment: I don't know how to describe to thank you. I have found my error of creating 'FlowLayoutPanel'. Now it can store the content of all the text boxes on it using your recursively iterate through its children method. Again thank you so much for your time.